# Order confirm email sent out slowly

Tags: email

I'm testing email. When I subscribe newsletter, I got subscription success email immediately

but when I place test order, I got the order confirm email after 10 ~ 20 seconds (time is different whenever I test)

Can I know what should I check or solution?

Comment: john G,are you developer ya enterputer?

Answer (score 1):

Magento is taken to send the order confirmation email.Because of there are lot of models need for ending.Just like `Order model,Order item model,order payment model and order shipment` models.

If it is taken more lot times then you need debug during  order place. Just like enable system.log and exception.log

Study [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)